# Query .SQL File (without loading to database)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a folder full of MySQL files. The process of writing each backup to their own database, and then querying is one option, but all I want to do is `SELECT` information from them.

My question: Is there a way to query these databases locally? This will eventually be used within a larger PHP script, so I have the option of using PHP if neccesary.

Comment: You want to read the data directly from the files?

Comment: Yes exactly, querying a local file without writing it to a database

Comment: csv or text files with other known delimiter can be used as a local database, but mysql file is not the right choice to parse. The best solution is to import the files into the database and pull your data from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found myself in a similar situation. I haven't found a way to query without first loading the database however there are other ways of extracting data. You can use pattern matching and then parse the data if needed. The following is an example of a regular expression which will return a particular row value for a row match (see group #2 results): http://regexr.com/3gf9p. This example is extracting the 'active_plugins' row from a WordPress database backup.

From the command line you can use perl to run the pattern and store the results in a bash variable.

```
active_plugins=`perl -n -e '/(\047active_plugins\047,\047)(.+?)(\047,\047yes\047\),)/&& print $2' ~/Backup/websitename.com/wp-content/mysql.sql`
```

In this example the results will be serialized and slashes added. You can pass that through a PHP file to parse.

```
php unserialize.php $active_plugins
```

Here is what's inside the `unserialize.php` file

```
<?php
print_r( unserialize( stripslashes( $argv[1] ) ) );
```

If you are unfamiliar with writing your own regular expressions I'd highly recommend watching this series: https://laracasts.com/series/understanding-regular-expressions. It was a huge help to me. One thing you may have noticed is I'm using `\047` instead of a single quote `'`. That is due to issues with escaping on the command line.